# store output of "which" command in a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to store the output the `which` command. Here's what I've tried:

```
OUT=$(which gsutil)
echo "$(OUT)"
```

But it doesn't work and prints an empty line.

Comment: `echo "${OUT}"`

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: `"$(OUT)"` thinks `OUT` as a command, not a variable. You might be mistaking with `${}`: `echo "${OUT}"`

Comment: @0stone0 the link doesn't help, I'm doing exactly the same and it doesn't work

Comment: `echo "${OUT}"` still doesn't work

Comment: No no no no, you're not doing the same; he is doing `echo "${OUTPUT}"` Note the `{}` **and not** `()`

Comment: that still doesn't solve the problem

Comment: what's the output of : `which gsutil` ?

Comment: @User123 `/home/miki/.local/bin/gsutil`

Comment: `echo "$(OUT)"` should produce an error, unless there's really a file named `OUT` in `$PATH`. Do you really run the above commands exactly? Spaces are significant in bash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `which` command is a broken heritage from the C-Shell and is better left alone in Bourne-like shells.

Instead use `command -v`:

```bash
OUT=$(command -v gsutil)
echo "${OUT}"
```

Comment: But of course, storing the standard output only so you can immediately `echo` it to standard output is a [useless use of `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Comment: It is. I sure hope that the variable will be used differently by the questioneer.